# Python 3 unexpected error TypeError

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to create a python3 script that uses the Euclidean Algorithm to find the GCD but I keep on getting an error.

Code:

```
firstnum = input("Enter the first number: ")
secondnum = input("Enter the second number: ")

if firstnum == secondnum:
    print("GCD is: {}").format(firstnum)
    quit()

if firstnum > secondnum:
    while True:
        thirdnum = firstnum % secondnum
        firstnum = secondnum
        secondnum = thirdnum
        if thirdnum == 0:
            print("GCD is: {}").format(firstnum)
            quit()
        else:
            continue

if firstnum < secondnum:
    while True:
        thirdnum = secondnum % firstnum
        secondnum = firstnum
        firstnum = thirdnum
        if thirdnum ==0:
            print("GCD is: {}").format(secondnum)
            quit()
        else:
            continue
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "..\Playground\", line 21, in <module>
   thirdnum = secondnum % firstnum
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

If there is a way to fix this error please explain how and why it occurred in the first place. I am also new to string formatting so if you know a more efficient way of printing strings with variables please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This operation is actually trying to perform string formatting

```
thirdnum = firstnum % secondnum
```

If you were attempting to perform a modulus operation you need to convert to `int`

```
firstnum = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
secondnum = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
```